# Better way to handle adding new table in a query which contains union of tables which have same column names but table name and data are different

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I want to rewrite the query to get the data from all the tables, currently I have 12 tables which contains exact same column names but have different table name and content. To get all the records I am currently union them like below.

```
select ct.id, ct.code, ct.name, ct.created_date, ct.updated_date, 
mt.id, mt.section, mt.description, mt.image_path
from client_1_tbl as ct
left outer join master_tbl as mt ON ct.id = mt.client_id
where ct.code in ('101','102','103')

UNION

select ct.id,ct.code, ct.name, ct.created_date, ct.updated_date, 
mt.id, mt.section, mt.description, mt.image_path
from client_2_tbl as ct
left outer join master_tbl as mt ON ct.id = mt.client_id
where ct.code in ('201','202','203')

UNION

select ct.id, ct.code, ct.name, ct.created_date, ct.updated_date, 
mt.id, mt.section, mt.description, mt.image_path
from client_3_tbl as ct
left outer join master_tbl as mt ON ct.id = mt.client_id
where ct.code in ('301','302','303')
```

Here I have given example of tables how I am using them, as you can see I have a master table and joining it with client table, but since client_1, client_2, client_3, ...etc contains different table names so I am just union them to get all the records. But now these client tables are started increased to 12 client tables, due to which this query is taking so much time.

Kindly please let me know if is there any better way to write this query. Since the client tables will be keep on increasing for every release and i need to optimise this query to have minimal changes.

Comment: For SQL performance questions you need to provide table structure, index definitions and the execution plan (using Paste The Plan). In SQL, a query is a logical problem statement, how SQL Server translates that into an execution plan is completely database specific, hence why in general its not possible to offer performance advice based on a query itself.

Comment: That said for performance you should always use `UNION ALL` not `UNION`. Straight `UNION` performance a de-duplication which is very often slow.

Comment: If `mt.id` is a primary key of `master_table`, then at least you should change `union` to `union all`.

Comment: Hi Dale, is there any way where i can reduce the size of the query, since just because the table name is different i have to keep on doing them Union. So i am trying to get a better way to write this query.

Comment: @astentx Indeed mt.id is a primary key of master_table i could dry doing union_all. But i am trying to rewrite this query in a better way. because my client tables will going to be keep on increasing for every release. Just due to the table name is different i have to keep on doing union them.

Comment: Having changing/increasing tables names is a design flaw - change your database structure to not do that. Otherwise your two options are to keep modifying this query every time you add a new table, or use dynamic SQL (which is to be avoided if possible). There are potentially other ways to write the query, but it now depends what problem you are trying to solve, this question talks about performance. If you want to ask about better ways to handle adding new tables, you need a new question.

Comment: So union all them together and perform a single join to master table. There is not so much to change. All depends on current indexes and selectivity of `ct.code in ...` predicate

Comment: @Dale, This is my product requirement, which i cannot change because we have to store each client data in a different table. This query we are using for reporting purpose and i am trying to enhance it, if i there is any better way, if not i have to live with same. :(

Comment: @astentx can you please give me a sample how i can do a single join which you have mentioned if possible. That would be of great help, i could try that.

Comment: "This is my product requirement, which i cannot change because we have to store each client data in a different table." well if I was you I would kick back against this requirement... its a terrible design. But if you are sticking with it as it is, then provide the required information asked for above for performance questions. Changing the query as astentx suggests is not necessarily going to make any performance difference, its the `union all` that will make the difference. As I said above, making random changes to the query to try and address performance issues is backwards.

Comment: @Dale for all the client tables we have indexing on id and code column and for master table there is indexing on id.

Comment: @Dale Thanks for suggesting to edit the quetion, now i have got the proper words which is my matching my need.

Comment: This question is not answerable without table and index definitions, and a query plan. But you could try `union all` all the tables first in a CTE, then join that result to the `master` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `UNION ALL` as it almost invariably performs better than `UNION`.
2. You can sub-query you client data and then join you master data in a single join (this probably won't improve performance, but might be neater for you).
3. For any further performance advice you need to provide all the data requested, table definitions, index definitions and the execution plan.

```
select
    ct.id, ct.code, ct.[name], ct.created_date, ct.updated_date 
    , mt.id, mt.section, mt.[description], mt.image_path
from (
    select ct.id, ct.code, ct.[name], ct.created_date, ct.updated_date, 
    from client_1_tbl as ct
    where ct.code in ('101','102','103')

    -- Use a union all for better performance
    union all

    select ct.id,ct.code, ct.[name], ct.created_date, ct.updated_date, 
    from client_2_tbl as ct
    where ct.code in ('201','202','203')

    -- etc ...
) ct
-- Join here to avoid multiple joins
left outer join master_tbl as mt ON ct.id = mt.client_id;
```

I should point out though, that in most cases when you have a multi-tenanted database, you should be using a single table and storing the owner of the client in another column. Then you don't run into these scaling issues.